# Is there a way to use a fine-tuned model in dialogflow-cx agents generators?

Tags: dialogflow-cx, google-generativeai

I would like to fine-tune the Text-Bison model with my own datasets and then use it within generators in a Dialogflow CX agent. Currently, I am unable to see the fine-tuned model that I created in the Vertex AI Generative Studio in the model dropdown for generators. Could someone please let me know if this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately not right now. You can use only text-bison